# How to access object using string value

Tags: string, file, ada

I have a file that I wanted to read and apply the new values to an object. How do I use the string name to look for the desired object and update the value. Do note that content in file.txt can be over 1000 lines long and order will changes so I can't have if statement to check each condition.

```
file.txt
>A 1
>B 2
>D 5
```

.

```
desired result
Sample.A := 1;
Sample.B := 2;
Sample.D := 5;
```

Comment: Don’t see why you can’t have an if statement; there would be rather a lot of `elsif`s. You certainly can’t take a random string from an input file and decide dynamically whether a particular record type has an attribute with that name! If that’s what you need to do, try e.g. Python.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to declare your object to be an array indexed by an enumeration type whose values are the identifiers. For instance, if the identifiers are the symbols A through Z you might define the array as:

```
subtype Index is Character range 'A'..'Z';
type Collection is array(Index) of Integer;
Idx : Index;
Value : Integer;
The_Collection : Collection;

while not End_Of_File(Input_File) loop
   Get(Idx);
   Get(Value);
   Skip_Line;
   The_Collection(Idx) := Value;
end loop;
```

Of course you will need to "with" the appropriate I/O packages.

Comment: Interesting. How would you go about this if instead of character enum, it is a String like some of the identifiers  can be as long as 20 characters

Comment: The length of an enumeration type not contain any blanks and must begin with a letter. For instance, you could declare an enumeration such as:
type Cities is (San_Francisco, London, Berlin, Tokyo, Honolulu);